# Meteor: Access Functions from Client, Run on Server

Tags: meteor, methods, public

I'm attempting to create a program where I use the Steam API. I want to be able to call the method to retrieve a user's info from the client, while keeping the actual code of the method secret from the client, since it contains an API Key. I tried defining the methods as global in a server folder, like this:

```
key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

Meteor.steamFunctions = {
    getName: function(user){
        var userSteamId = user.profile.id;
        Meteor.http.get('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=' + key + '&steamids=' + userSteamId, function(error, resultJSON){
            if (error){
                return 'Error in Steam API';
            } else {
                var json = JSON.parse(resultJSON);
                return json.personaname;
            }
        })
    },

    getPic: function(user){
        var userSteamId = user.profile.id;
        Meteor.http.get('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=' + key + '&steamids=' + userSteamId, function(error, resultJSON){
            if (error){
                return 'Error in Steam API';
            } else {
                var json = JSON.parse(resultJSON);
                return json.avatarfull;
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I then try to call it like this in a client-side script:

```
if (Meteor.isClient){
    Template.profile.helpers({
        'getName': function(){
            return Meteor.steamFunctions.getName(Meteor.user());
        }
    });
}
```

That, however, throws

```
Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getName' of undefined
    at Object.Template.profile.helpers.getName
```

How can I go about keeping the key secret to the user while still accessing the data?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is not quite as simple as adding a property to the `Meteor` global.  Also, the remote method/call API to do this will involve asynchronous code.

Put the call to the API, with the secret API key, on the server side in code only visible on the server, e.g. the `./server` subdirectory.  Define a [Meteor.method](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-methods) on the server side that can be called with [Meteor.call](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-call) on the client side.

In the server side Meteor method there are [method security checks](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/security-with-methods) you can make to check for a logged in user or userid, and use this to decide whether to make the calls or ignore the request.  You can throw a new Meteor.Error from the server side if a request is improper or there is an error, but these take resources to communicate.

The thing to understand about Meteor is that it has nothing magical to change how Javascript behaves on the browser or the server.  The server is ultimately running nodejs.  Objects defined on the server do not magically migrate to the client, or vice versa.  If an object is defined on both, it is actually two separate pieces of code.

Therefore, in the client code, the `Meteor.call` to call the server-side code from the browser... is actually using an existing websocket or ajax API that is asynchronous in nature.  This means that you will need to structure client code to provide callback functions on the browser to handle the asynchronously returned results of looking up `Name` or `Pic`.  A direct return and imperative coding style is not possible.

Typically you'll want to update something on a user's screen as a result of information returned from a lookup.  The usual Meteor coding is to have the callback function update a [session global variable](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/session) with `Session.set()`. Templates can reference these session variables, and through an implied or explicit Tracker.autorun(), the screen can be updated when the API returns the data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Move your `steamFunctions` into [methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods) which are defined only on the server.
2. Properly invoke the methods from the client.

Below is some example code based on your original question. Please note this has not been tested and may require some tweaking.

**server/methods.js**

```js
const KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const URL = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002';

Meteor.methods({
  getName() {
    const userSteamId = Meteor.user().profile.id;
    const params = {
      key: KEY,
      steamids: userSteamId,
    };

    try {
      var result = HTTP.get(URL, { params });

      // Double check this - I have no idea what this API returns. The value
      // you want may be nested under result, like result.data or something.
      return JSON.parse(result).personaname;
    } catch (e) {
      // Something bad happened - maybe throw an error.
      return false;
    }
  },
});
```

Note this method is defined on the server, so we don't expose our `KEY` to the client. Also note we are using the synchronous version of the `HTTP` api, so the value can be returned to the client.

**client/lib/user.js**

```js
Tracker.autorun(function () {
  user = Meteor.user();
  if (user && user.profile && user.profile.id) {
    Meteor.call('getName', (err, name) => {
      Session.set('steamName', name);
    });
  } else {
    Session.set('steamName', '');
  }
});
```

When the user logs is or is updated, get the steam name and set a global session variable.

**client/templates/profile.js**

```js
Template.profile.helpers({
  getName: function () {
    return Session.get('steamName');
  },
});
```

Read the `steamName` session variable for use in your template.

Comment: Thanks for the response... my trouble now is the method is called from the client before the user is actually "logged in", thus giving me an "cannot access from undefined" error.. I tried using waitOn Meteor.user() in the iron-router router file, I also tried installing fast-render... neither seem to work. Do you know of an easier way to accomplish the wait? Either way, thanks for the answer, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Yeah that should be an easy fix. Before I add it, can you tell me when the steam name would change and when the profile template is rendered? For example if the name never changes and the profile is rendered a lot, you'll make a lot of unnecessary calls. In that case it should probably be set globally.

Comment: So... I kinda took another path, and I'm not sure if it's feasible/the right one. I was thinking about making a collection where it holds all of the info, and the info gets inserted on onCreateUser(), and have the info called and updated every time they login with onLogin()... then having them access the data through the collection. I'm not sure if this is the best way to get it done, however. Do you have any opinions on that? Sorry I'm kind of taking you on a ride with this... I just don't know the best way to do things :)

Comment: There are a lot of ways to approach this problem. Your suggestion sounds like a good one, but you may want to just directly write to the user's doc instead of using another collection - I guess it depends on how much and what data is required. I updated the answer with an example using a global autorun and session variable. That's a simple solution which should update at the appropriate times. The only time I wouldn't use this would be if your app constantly updates the user's document. You can always put a console log in `getName` to see how frequently it's being called if that's a concern.